# Sorting DataSet Rows in a very specific non alphabetical order

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, dataset

So I have a simple DataSet that has table `BatchSummary` that looks like this:
 [image]

I want to sort the rows in this table in very specific order. The table always has 5 rows and the Values of Description always look like this (example):

- Anna
- Frank
- Bill
- Marco
- David

I want the DataSet to be ordered like this in this very specific order:

- Marco
- Bill
- David
- Anna
- Frank

I tried to do it using the DefaultView Property of my DataTable like this

```
dataSet.BatchSummary.DefaultView.Item(0).DataView.Sort = "Marco, Bill, David, Anna, Frank"
```

But I get an `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`

How can I sort this?

Comment: `DataView.Sort()` [expects a column name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort(v=vs.110).aspx), not a set of values..

Comment: I have done this by adding a field to my database table which I named DisplayOrder. I numbered it accordingly. Then I added an Order By clause to the Select statement ... Order By DisplayOrder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DataView.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't support this, it expects a column.

I'd use `Linq-To-DataTable` which is much more powerful:

```
var descriptionOrder = new List<string>{ "Marco", "Bill", "David", "Anna", "Frank" };

var orderedBatchSummary = dataSet.BatchSummary.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(batch => descriptionOrder.IndexOf(batch.Description))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: what if the datatable is data bound? will this code work even the n?

Comment: @zackraiyan: what means data bound? The `DataSet`/`DataTable` is an in-memory collection that is for example filled via DataAdapter. If you want to fill it ordered you have to use pure sql(if the source was a database). But OP hasn't shown anything about the datasource. He just wanted to order an existing DataSet.